# PHP Ajax Display Records From Drop Down List then Update Records are not working

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, database

My application asks the user to select the date from the drop down list. After selecting the date, it will display the list of students who took the exam on that date. The user will then can encode grades then save it. But the saving part is not working.

Here is the code.

```
$queryselect = mysql_query("SELECT examdateno, examdate from tbl_examdate ORDER BY examdate DESC");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SPORT Qualifying Exam System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/component.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>         
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script>
        function showUser(str) {
            if (str == "") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
                return;
            } else {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }                    
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "encodeinterviewajax.php?q=" + str, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="../images/qes_logob.png" alt="logo">
        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
        <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
    </header>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <a href="encodeinterview.php">
                <li>Encode Grades</li>
            </a> 
            <a href="viewinterview.php">
                <li>View Grades</li>
            </a>               
            <a href="../index.php">
                <li>Logout</li>
            </a>  
        </ul>
    </div>


    <script>
        $(".cross").hide();
        $(".menu").hide();
        $(".hamburger").click(function () {
            $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function () {
                $(".hamburger").hide();
                $(".cross").show();
            });
        });

        $(".cross").click(function () {
            $(".menu").slideToggle("slow", function () {
                $(".cross").hide();
                $(".hamburger").show();
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="content">
        <form>
            <h1>Exam Dates</>
                <select name="examdate" id="examDate" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                    <option>Select Exam Date</option>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($queryselect)) {
                        echo "<option value={$row['examdateno']}>{$row['examdate']}</option>\n";
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
        </form>
    </div>
        <div id="txtHint">Examinees will be listed here</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the php file

```
<?php
include '../configuration.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/component.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/grid.css">
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);


    $sql = mysql_query("select s.sno, s.fname, s.lname, s.examdate, s.interviewgrade, s.gwa from student s inner join tbl_examdate e on s.examdate=e.examdate where e.examdateno=$q");


    ?>
    <div class="as_wrapper">    
        <div class="as_grid_container">
            <div class="as_gridder" id="as_gridder"></div> <!-- GRID LOADER -->
            <form method="post" action="">
                <table class="as_gridder_table">
                    <tr class="grid_header">
                        <td><div class="grid_heading">Student No.</div></td>
                        <td><div class="grid_heading">First Name</div></td>
                        <td><div class="grid_heading">Last Name</div></td>
                        <td><div class="grid_heading">Exam Date</div></td>
                        <td><div class="grid_heading">Interview Grade</div></td>
                        <td><div class="grid_heading">GWA</div></td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                        ?>
                        <tr class="<?php
                        $i+=1;
                        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                            echo 'even';
                        } else {
                            echo 'odd';
                        }
                        ?>">
                            <td><?php $sno[]=$row['sno'];echo $row['sno']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php $fname[]=$row['fname']; echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php $lname[]=$row['lname'];echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['examdate']; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" name="interview[]"></td>
                            <td><input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" name="gwa[]"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6"><button id="btnUpdate">Save</button>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <?php

            if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){
                for($i=0;$i<sizeof($sno);$i++){
                    $interview = $_POST['interview'][$i];
                    $gwa = $_POST['gwa'][$i];
                    $sql1=  mysql_query("UPDATE student SET gwa='$gwa', interviewgrade='$interview' where fname='$fname[$i]' AND lname='$lname[$i]' ");
                    header('Location: encodeinterview.php');
                }
            }           
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not properly understood. Can you specify where your problem is more elaborately. Additionally, you should use prepared statement with `pdo` or `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated and will be removed in future.

Comment: The update is not working in the php file.